# Vue transition mode don't work when combined with v-for and v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, vuetify.js, animate.css

in Vue with Vuetify, I want to change dynamically v-cards with `animate.css`, and I'm facing a problem. The `out-in` mode doesn't want to work in this situation. Fade-in and fade-out animations are moving at the same time. How can force it to start the fade-in animation after ending a fade-in?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      number: 1,
      items: [
        {
          text: "a",
          number: 1
        },
        {
          text: "b",
          number: 2
        },
        {
          text: "c",
          number: 3
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <transition mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft" leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight">
      <v-card dark class="ma-3" v-if="number === item.number">
        <p>{{item.text}}</p>
      </v-card>
    </transition>
  </div>
  <br>
  <v-btn @click="number++; if(number === 4) number = 1;">Next</v-btn>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/km2442/pen/zgmmwz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is wrong ?

Your transition is inside a loop which means after the rendering you will have multiple `transitions` that have no relation to each other (`mode` doesn't work)... this is how your template will  look like after rendering :

```html
<div key="0">
    <transition mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft" leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight">
      <v-card dark class="ma-3" v-if="true">
        <p>a</p>
      </v-card>
    </transition>
 </div>
 <div key="1">
    <transition mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft" leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight">
     <!-- <v-card dark class="ma-3" v-if="false">
        <p>b</p>
      </v-card> -->
    </transition>
 </div>
 <div key="2">
    <transition mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft" leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight">
      <!-- <v-card dark class="ma-3" v-if="false">
        <p>c</p>
      </v-card> --> 
    </transition>
 </div>
 <div key="3">
    <transition mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft" leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight">
      <!-- <v-card dark class="ma-3" v-if="false">
        <p>d</p>
      </v-card> -->
    </transition>
 </div>
```

so when you press next you are jumping from a transition to another one ...and in this case the `mode` is lost .

### How i fix this ?

we just need to wrap our whole items inside a transition, so in this case there is only one `transition` that will detect when an element is going out and a new one is coming in (`mode` will work) :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      number: 1,
      items: [{
          text: "a",
          number: 1
        },
        {
          text: "b",
          number: 2
        },
        {
          text: "c",
          number: 3
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <transition mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft" leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <v-card dark class="ma-3" v-if="number === item.number" :key="index">
        <p>{{item.text}}</p>
      </v-card>
  </template>
  </transition>
  <br>
  <v-btn @click="number++; if(number === 4) number = 1;">Next</v-btn>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `<transition-group>`, when iterating with a `v-for` loop.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"> 
</script><script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
 <transition-group mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft" leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <v-card dark class="ma-3" v-if="number === item.number">
    <p>{{item.text}}</p>
  </v-card>
 </transition-group>
</div>
<br>
<v-btn @click="number++; if(number === 4) number = 1;">Next</v-btn>
</div>
```

Documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions